# Excel data load into Azure SQL using SQL query

Tags: sql, azure

Wants to load Excel data into Azure SQL using SQL query.
As openrowset is not allowed in Azure, Please help me to write query to insert excel data into Azure DB.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Quick steps:

1. Import your excel or csv into Local sql server using import task
2. Using the import table, create a Sql script with insert data statement.
3. Run this script on your Azure Database

The queries are given clearly in MS site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql

I recommend you to refer topics in these links:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-load-with-bcp/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel

Comment: I need sql query... we have requirement that need to upload excel using query.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can run a distributed query, you have to enable the ad hoc distributed queries server configuration option

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

example with OPENDATASOURCE

```
USE ImportFromExcel;
GO
SELECT * INTO Data_dq
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Data Source=D:\Desktop\Data.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Data$];
GO
```

You can create a linked server from SQL Server Management Studio, or by running the system stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver

```
DECLARE @RC int

DECLARE @server     nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @srvproduct nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @provider   nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @datasrc    nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @location   nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @provstr    nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @catalog    nvarchar(128)

-- Set parameter values
SET @server =     'EXCELLINK'
SET @srvproduct = 'Excel'
SET @provider =   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
SET @datasrc =    'D:\Desktop\Data.xlsx'
SET @provstr =    'Excel 12.0'

EXEC @RC = [master].[dbo].[sp_addlinkedserver] @server, @srvproduct, 
@provider,
@datasrc, @location, @provstr, @catalog
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql

Comment: OPENDATASOURCE not allowed in Azure SQL   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql

Answer (score -1):

You can use OPENROWSET:

```
SELECT * INTO EXCEL_IMPORT
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Excel\Spreadsheet.xls; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

Comment: OPENROWSET not allowed in Azure SQL